# Nsis7z not getting it.

Tags: nsis

Do i am missing something here. I found Nsis7z and found the example.

```
File "ArchiveName.7z"
Nsis7z::Extract "ArchiveName.7z"
Delete "$OUTDIR\ArchiveName.7z"
```

So I tool that and created:

```
Section 
# Init temporary folder $PLUGINSDIR
InitPluginsDir

# Include 7-zip archive
SetOutPath "$PLUGINSDIR"
ReserveFile "F:\test.7z"

# Extract archive
Nsis7z::Extract "$PLUGINSDIR\test.7z"
Delete "$PLUGINSDIR\test.7z"
SectionEnd
```

I see the temp folder get created, but nothing ever extracts to the temp folder except the nsis7z.dll.

what am I missing. It looks so basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Section
# Init temporary folder $PLUGINSDIR
InitPluginsDir

# Include 7-zip archive
SetOutPath "$PLUGINSDIR"
ReserveFile D:\test.7z

File Test.7z
# Extract archive
Nsis7z::ExtractWithCallback "$PLUGINSDIR\test.7z"
Delete "$PLUGINSDIR\test.7z"
SectionEnd
```

You forget to add **File Test.7z**

Comment: Wow, man I cant belive I over looked that. Thanks. (Feeling dumb now)